# ajax request data not getting loaded - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to populate a ListBox dynamically. But it's not working with ajax request.

Here's what I am doing.

My Ajax request :

```
angular.module("confessions_module").factory("Universities",function(){

    var service = {};

        service.getUniversitiesAjax=function(callback)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'myurl',
                success:function(e)
                {
                    universitiesList = $.parseJSON(e);
                    callback(universitiesList);
                }

            });

//                var a = [{ 'name':'asdasdsad','id':123},{ 'name':'mozi','id':123}];
 //              callback(a)
        }
    return service;
});
```

My Controller calling the function and populating the array:

```
   Universities.getUniversitiesAjax(
    function(university)
    {

        for(var i=0;i<university.length;i++)
        {
            var unii = { 'name' : university[i].name , 'id' : university[i].id };
            $scope.unis.push(unii);
        }
    }
);
```

My View:

```
                   <select id="dd_universities">
                        <option ng-repeat="uni in unis">{{uni.name}}</option>
                    </select>
```

Now there are two lines commented in `My Ajax Request` code. When I `uncomment` those two lines , my data gets populated with no problem. But whenever I try to populate it using the ajax request code as it is happening now. It does not work. What could be the problem ?

Comment: you should be using $http instead of $.ajax otherwise you may face some problems

Comment: $http is provided by angular ?

Comment: Yeah it's an injectable service and then you can simply `$http.get("myurl").success(function(){})` The largest benefit of this is that responses are digested inside of the angular framework, meaning you don't have to use `$scope.$apply()`. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX callback is executed "outside" of Angular, so even though you are changing your scope properties:

```
$scope.unis.push(unii);
```

Angular will not notice these changes.  Call `$scope.$apply()` after your `for` loop.  This will cause Angular to run a [digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime), which will notice your changes and update your view(s).